# "by virtue of" & "by means of" & "by dint of"

Tags: prepositions, difference

What are the differences between "by virtue of" and "by means of" and "by dint of"

What is the most usual for the native English speaker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*By virtue of* means *because of* (usually some advantage).

> He gained the promotion by virtue of his seniority.

*By means of* refers to the method used to achieve something.

> The weight was lifted by means of a hoist.

*By dint of* often refers to the work done to achieve something.

> She passed the exam by dint of hard work.

Comment: _"Will I be right?"_ 'By means of' is the best choice for that sentence, yes.